Rust RP2040 `entry` differences
I made an RP2040 board, and am trying to program it in Rust.  See modified template at https://github.com/Erhannis/rp2040-project-template/tree/erhannis/raw_rp2040 .  Now, since this isn't a Pico board, I dutifully followed the instructions in the Cargo.toml and uncommented like so:
# If you're not going to use a Board Support Package you'll need these:
rp2040-hal = { version = "0.10", features = ["rt", "critical-section-impl"] }
rp2040-boot2 = "0.3"

and swapped the uses of rp-pico for rp2040-hal.
Weird thing, the code runs fine...IFF I use rp_pico::entry;.  If instead I use rp2040_hal::entry;, the code doesn't run, apparently never enters.  How is this possible?  Looking at rp_pico::entry, it looks like it just aliases back to rp2040_hal::entry:
pub extern crate rp2040_hal as hal;
...
#[cfg(feature = "rt")]
pub use hal::entry;

This works:
// use rp2040_hal::entry;
use rp_pico::entry;

and this does not:
use rp2040_hal::entry;
// use rp_pico::entry;

but they should be the same code.  What gives?

From what I can tell, it is as you say: they should be the exact same thing. Assuming this is causing the problem (and its not actually caused by a mis-deployment or other outside factor making you think this change was the problem), it is theoretically possible for this change to impact the build since "unused" dependencies may be left out of final linking. But its hard to tell if your code fits that scenario. Can you try doing use rp2040_hal::entry; with extern crate rp_pico;?

@kmdreko Sorry, I missed your question, somehow - yes, extern crate rp_pico seems to suffice instead of use rp_pico::entry.  And, following a suspicion, I found that it's that rp_pico specifies the bootloader, and by copying the following code into mine I no longer need rp_pico:
#[link_section = ".boot2"]
#[no_mangle]
#[used]
pub static BOOT2_FIRMWARE: [u8; 256] = rp2040_boot2::BOOT_LOADER_W25Q080;
``` (with linebreaks inserted as appropriate.)
If you want to turn this into an answer, I'd accept it.
